# how to detect a repeated pattern in a string using re module of python

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to match a string using re module of python in which a pattern may repeat or not. The string starts with three alphabetical parts separated by `:`, then there is a `=` following with another alphabetical part. The string can finish here or continue to repeat patterns of `alphabetical_part=alphabetical_part` which are separated with a comma. Both samples are as below:

```
Finishes with just one repeat ==> aa:bb:cc=dd
Finishes with more than one repeat ==> aa:bb:cc=dd,ee=ff,gg=hh
```

As you see, there can't be a comma at the end of the string. I have wrote a pattern for matching this:

```
>>> pt = re.compile(r'\S+:\S+:[\S+=\S+$|,]+')
```

`re.match` returns a match object for this, but when I group the repeat pattern, I got something strange, see:

```
>>> st = 'xx:zz:rr=uu,ii=oo,ff=ee'
>>> pt = re.compile(r'\S+:\S+:([\S+=\S+$|,]+)')
>>> pt.findall(st)
['e']
```

I'm not sure if I wrote the right pattern or not; how can I check it? If it's wrong, what is the right answer though?

Comment: "_how can I check it?_": If you ever want to check your regex is doing you can look at [debuggex.com](http://debuggex.com/) or [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/). [Here's what your regex is currently doing](http://regex101.com/r/eU3kS1/1). It seems to me that `ee:ff` does not fit. "_The string can finish here or continue to repeat patterns of alphabetical_part=alphabetical_part which are separated with a comma_". `ee:ff` is separated by a colon not an equals sign.

Comment: Also, what are you expecting as the output? Do you want `['rr=uu,ii=oo,ff==ee']` or `['rr=uu','ii=oo','ff=ee']`?

Comment: @skamazin I corrected the `ee:ff` part. Plus, I want nothing actually, I just want to check matching the string with the pattern.

Comment: If you want to check it matches, just see if it's in the return array of `re.findall(...)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """ foo bar bar foo
xx:zz:rr=uu,ii=oo,ff=ee
aa:bb:cc=dd
xx:zz:rr=uu,ii=oo,ff=ee
bar foo"""
>>> m = re.findall(r'^[^=: ]+?[=:](?:[^=:,]+?[:=][^,\n]+?)(?:,[^=:,]+?[=:][^,\n]+?)*$', s, re.M)
>>> m
['xx:zz:rr=uu,ii=oo,ff=ee', 'aa:bb:cc=dd', 'xx:zz:rr=uu,ii=oo,ff=ee']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
st = 'xx:zz:rr=uu,ii=oo,ff=ee'
m = re.findall(r'\w+:\w+:(\w+=\w+)((?:,\w+=\w+)*)', st )

>>> m
[('rr=uu', ',ii=oo,ff=ee')]
```

Don't use `\S` because this will also match `:`. It's better to use `\w`

Or :

```
re.findall(r'\w+:\w+:(\w+=\w+(?:,\w+=\w+)*)', st )[0].split(',')
# This will return: ['rr=uu', 'ii=oo', 'ff=ee']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more readable regex that should work for you:

```
\S+?:\S+?:(?:\S+?=\S+?.)+
```

It makes use of a non-capturing group `(?:...)` and the plus `+` repeat token to match on one or more of the "*`alphabetical_part=alphabetical_part`*"

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> str = """ foo bar
... foo bar bar foo
... xx:zz:rr=uu,ii=oo,ff=ee
... aa:bb:cc=dd
... xx:zz:rr=uu,ii=oo,ff=ee
... bar foo """
>>> pat = re.compile(ur'\S+?:\S+?:(?:\S+?=\S+?.)+')
>>> re.findall(pat, str)
['xx:zz:rr=uu,ii=oo,ff=ee', 'aa:bb:cc=dd', 'xx:zz:rr=uu,ii=oo,ff=ee']
```